# Who decides how consumer electronics could and should be labeled and advertised?

Tags: united-states, international-law, trade, international-standards

Let's suppose I'm a somewhat-educated computer-science-wise citizen who is very dissatisfied with inconsistent digital storage drive capacity labeling, where manufacturers use `GB` (base-10 SI metric decimal `giga` unit prefix equals to 1000 in power of 3) instead of base-2 binary scale units (e.g. `GiB` with prefix `gibi` equals to 1024 in power of 3).

The motivation for this complaint could be that the binary notation is more native for computing devices like CPUs. It is also a bit inconsistent to use binary notation for bits in bytes (1 byte = 8 bit),  but change it to decimal midways. Something doesn't feel right in this situation.

Aforementioned means that instead of expected **64** **binary** `GB` I could get **64** **decimal** `GB` which is around **59** **binary** `GB`.

Hence the questions:

- Who decides how those products could be labeled?
- If I would like to make the standards more consistent, who should I ask for help?
- To whom should a possible petition for more correct labeling be addressed to?

The context is US.

Comment: The relevant law is not international but national (or EU wide for EU citizens). Food labeling is heavily regulated in a lot of countries. It seems though that very little regulation exists for consumer electronics so the companies can write more or less whatever they want.

Comment: You should write to whoever makes laws in your country. That is vague, yes.

Comment: Generally, everything which is not illegal is legal. So if there's no law against it then the manufacturer can do what they like. There should be a law about misleading advertising, but innocent until proven guilty, and the manufacturer has a plausible excuse for why it is not misleading.

Comment: This would be an ok question if you narrowed down the scope to some country or countries. E.g. in the US the FCC would have such power. There are basically no international agreements (=international law) on labelling electronics. The US has its on regulations, the EU's likewise etc. This is a reason why getting [the same] electronics products marketed in different areas is not straightforward.

Comment: N.B. the varying per-country regulations is called a "not-tariff barrier" to trade. https://voxeu.org/article/global-trade-protection-and-role-non-tariff-barriers

Comment: I agree with Fizz, I think this is an on-topic question, but as it stands currently it is pretty broad. If you can narrow it down to a specific country or region I would vote to re-open.

Comment: Relevant article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix#Legal_disputes

Comment: and btw there's nothing "fake" about SI prefixes for data storage. Both Linux and Mac show the SI units. It's only Windows that continues the silliness of binary prefixes.

Comment: @VELFR - I find the question interesting, but it is indeed too broad for SE Q&A format. I have narrowed it down to US only to be able to reopen it and have a chance to get an answer.

Comment: @Fizz: I don't think the FCC has jurisdiction in cases like the one the OP is asking about.  They can (AFAIK) regulate radio frequency emissions from devices.  I think what the OP is really asking for is a government agency to protect him from his own ignorance, and I don't think even the CPSC goes that far unless there's some halfway plausible physical danger.